# Is there a way to associate an index to the selected value from a OKCANCELLIST prompt in LotusScript?

Tags: lotusscript

Example

```
headerName(0) = FirstName
headerName(1) = LastName
headerName(2) = NotesId

selectHeader = workspace.Prompt(PROMPT_OKCANCELLIST, "", "Select a header name.", headerName(0), headerName)
```

Let's say I am another user and selected *FirstName* from the list and clicked ok, *selectHeader* will be equivalent to *FirstName* as well. However, I need to know too how to get the index of the selected item.

```
Messagebox *Return index of selected item*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no "aliases" that could be used in that prompt... So the "short" answer is: 
Nope, there is no way to find out, which selection the user took.

You have to code a workaround... One could be to prepare your array like this:

```
headerName(0) = "1. " & FirstName
headerName(1) = "2. " & LastName
headerName(2) = "3. " & NotesId
```

And then you could check for `StrLeft( selectHeader, ". " )`

Or you create a little form, that contains a DialogList- Field... Then you would use `ws.DialogBox()` to show the dialog and fill the choices for the field like `"FirstName|1" : "LastName|2" : "NotesID|3"`

Comment: I see. I'll try the little form. I don't really want to put any numbers together with the items. Eg. *"1. " & FirstName*

Answer (score 1):

You get the index this way:

```
ArrayGetIndex(headerName, selectHeader)
```

Comment: What if there's a scenario when there are duplicates?
    headerName(0) = FirstName
    headerName(1) = LastName
    headerName(2) = FirstName

Comment: In this case, you would get index of first occurrence. In your example it would be "0". If you have to care about that use aliases. But does it make sense to have duplicates in prompt box?